# mkvtoolnix 5.8.0 on trusty

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, plex

mkvtoolnix 5.8.0 is needed to convert movies in order to play on older Samsung TV's through plex. This explained I want to come straight to business :)

I'm unable to install 5.8.0, because requesting dependencies

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# dpkg --force-all -i mkvtool.deb
(Reading database ... 84999 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mkvtool.deb ...
Unpacking mkvtoolnix (5.8.0-1ubuntu1) over (5.8.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: mkvtoolnix: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 mkvtoolnix depends on libboost-filesystem1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1); however:
  Package libboost-filesystem1.49.0 is not installed.
 mkvtoolnix depends on libboost-regex1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1); however:
  Package libboost-regex1.49.0 is not installed.
 mkvtoolnix depends on libboost-system1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1); however:
  Package libboost-system1.49.0 is not installed.
 mkvtoolnix depends on libebml3; however:
  Package libebml3 is not installed.
 mkvtoolnix depends on liblzo2-2; however:
  Package liblzo2-2 is not installed.

Setting up mkvtoolnix (5.8.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
```

Can somebody help me in this, thx

Comment: You have dependency issues, install `gdebi` by `sudo apt-get install gdebi` and then open the file with `gdebi` so that it can take care of those dependencies too (if possible).. `sudo gdebi mkvtool.deb` ..otherwise open the `.deb` file with Software center or satisfy the dependencies yourself..

Comment: Thx for the tip, I will keep it in mind...in the meantime I downloaded & installed each dependency manually. It is working

Comment: We need to mark it as solved..either you post an answer or let me put an answer and select it as accepted then..

Answer (score -1):

Had similar problem. Turned out that I've added wrong OS version to `sources.list`. See here:
https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html#ubuntu

When I changed from Vivid to Trusty the problem resolved.